# Accessing pieces of combined model in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This might be difficult to explain but please bear with me... So, I have a model that combines two different models so that I can utilize data found in both in one view: Combined:

```
public class EventFullModel
{
    public AccessListModel AccessPointsList;
    public EventListModel EventList;
}
```

Access List Model:

```
public class AccessListModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AccessPoints { get; set; }
}
```

Event List Model:

```
public class EventListModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string T { get; set; }
    public virtual string C { get; set; }
    public virtual string M { get; set; }
    public virtual string L { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Events { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

I am currently getting an error which I believe stems from the fact that the controller method for this view originally returned just the `EventListModel` whereas now it is trying to return the `EventFullModel` since I changed the inheritance: `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Cred.Web.Models.EventFullModel>"`.  So at this point I am trying to edit the controller to make sure it attempts to return the correct model for the view.  My problem is the following:

This is a GET action method: `public ActionResult Index(int? id)`
Originally, the controller worked only with the `EventListModel`:

```
EventListModel model;
model = new EventListModel {
Id = 0,
T = "",
C = "",
M = "",
L = HttpContext.Session["L"].IsNull() ? "" : HttpContext.Session["L"].ToString(),
Events = new List<SelectListItem>(),
Skills =
        DbQueryExecutor.ExecuteQuery(new SkillsList()).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e.Certification, Value = e.Certification, Selected = false })
```

So I am basically wondering, how can I edit this to access those pieces of the `EventListModel` but have my `model = new EventFullModel?`

(Disclaimer: I have altered the names of a few things and I am working to edit a piece of software that I did not originally write so I am trying to change as little as possible in the hopes of not "breaking" other pieces of the software.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your `[Post]` action method of your controller is receiving an `EventFullModel` object as a parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestController(EventFullModel eventFullModel)
{
   var accessListModel = eventFullModel.AccessPointsList;
   var eventListModel = eventFullModel.EventList;

   accessListModel.Id;
....
   eventListModel.Id;
....
}
```

EDIT **

```
EventListModel model;
model = new EventListModel{
....

var accessListModel = new AccessListModel{
   Id = 0,
   AccessPoint = new List<SelectListItem>()
};

var eventFullModel = new EventFullModel{
   AccessPointsList = accessListModel,
   EventList = model
};

return View(eventFullModel);
```

I'm guessing since your controller was taking in a `int? id` before, this was the `id` of the `EventListModel`. If you want this `id` to continue working then there has to be a relationship between `EventListModel` and `AccessListModel`

Comment: I'm sorry but no, this is actually a GET action method.  it simply returns information from the server, it does not POST any information to it.  Also, it only recieves an `(int? id)` as a parameter.  I'll update my original post with that information.  Thank you though

Comment: I'm currently working on the code to use the AccessListModel in the controller but while I am, I was wondering something:  Doing this required `{get; set;}` declarations in the `EventFullModel`, should that affect my ability to use HTML helpers in my view? `<%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EventsList.L)%>`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to return an `EventFullModel` instead of an `EventListModel`?

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id) {
    return View(new EventFullModel {
        EventList = new EventListModel {
            Id = 0,
            T = "",
            C = "",
            M = "",
            L = ...,
            Events = new List<SelectListItem>(),
            Skills = ...
        },
        AccessPointsList = ... createYourAccessPointsModel ...
    });
}
```

Comment: That is true, I need to return an `EventFullModel` instead of `EventListModel`.  I am currently working through SOfanatic's solution however.